# A component mounted at two points

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and am trying to implement an HTML structure like this

```
<div class="heads">
    <div class="head">head1</div>
    <div class="head">head2</div>
    <div class="head">head3</div>
</div>
<div class="bodies">
    <div class="body">body1</div>
    <div class="body">body2</div>
    <div class="body">body3</div>
</div>
```

Each head-body pair (like `head1-body1`) belongs to a single component. Without changing the structure, how would I write such a component?

From my understanding, it needs to be "mounted" at two different points (in "heads" and in "bodies").

A practical example of such structure would be a tabbed dialog which has tab headers within the "heads" div and their contents within "bodies".

What I'm looking for is some code that would be able to translate this:

```
<Tabs ...>
    <Tab head="head1">body1</Tab>
    <Tab head="head2">body2</Tab>
    <Tab head="head3">body3</Tab>
</Tabs>
```

into the above HTML structure. Is that possible in React?

Comment: I would rethink your architecture instead...doesn't sound like the ideal way to decompose that, but hard to say without more details.

Comment: With the addition of the example you posted: don't confuse data, even related multiple pieces of data, as "components". Tab headers is some data. Tab body contents is some data. There is a Tab component that takes that data as props, and a Tabs component that is responsible for focus and layout and renders the active Tab. At least that's how I'd do it based on the somewhat bare-bones description of a generic UI component. It sounds like with the HTML structure in your example you would implement that by hiding/unhiding as the focused tab changes, but I'd do it entirely differently in React

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a natural fit in React, but you do have some options.

**Option 1**: You could bite the bullet and render the head and body components separately, just like you'd write the HTML separately. For example, Material-UI, one of the popular React component libraries, does this for its [Tabs component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/).

**Option 2**: Components are just code, so you can manipulate them however you want. (In the following example, I made up some unique IDs for each tab so that I have a `key` prop to keep React happy, and I'm also demonstrating dynamically adding/removing elements.)

```
function MyPage({hideTab3}) {
  const tabs = [
    { id: 1, header: 'head1', body: <MyBody1 /> },
    { id: 2, header: 'head2', body: <MyBody2 /> },
    !hideTab3 && { id: 3, header: 'head3', body: <MyBody3 /> },
  ].filter(Boolean);

  return (
    <div className="heads">
      {tabs.map(({id, head}) => <div className="head" key={id}>{head}</div>)}
    </div>
    <div className="bodies">
      {tabs.map(({id, body}) => <div className="body" key={id}>{body}</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Options 3:** You could use component slots, which can be [simple](https://daveceddia.com/pluggable-slots-in-react-components/) or [quite sophisticated](https://sandroroth.com/blog/react-slots).

Here's an example of the more sophisticated approach - a component can examine its child components' props and handle their slots themselves. I'm using TypeScript here to help enforce the restrictions on child components.

```
interface TabProps {
  head: ReactNode;
  children: ReactNode;
}

function Tab({ head, children }: TabProps) {
  return <div className="body">{children}</div>;
}

interface TabsProps {
  // `children` is normally a generic `ReactNode`; specify
  // a strong type here, since we manipulate child props.
  children:
    | ReactElement<TabProps, typeof Tab>
    | ReactElement<TabProps, typeof Tab>[];
}

function Tabs({ children }: TabsProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <ul className="heads">
        {Children.map(children, (tab, i) => (
          // Tab head loop: Extract out child props, as shown in
          // https://sandroroth.com/blog/react-slots#slots-by-type.
          //
          // Production-ready should maybe throw for non-Tab children.
          <li className="head" key={i}>
            {tab.props.head}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      {/* Bodies can show children's default renders. */}
      <div className="bodies">{children}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Tabs>
      <Tab head="head1">body 1</Tab>
      <Tab head="head2">body 2</Tab>
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

*Personally*, I'm less likely to use this approach - as mentioned in the [sandroroth.com](https://sandroroth.com/blog/react-slots#slots-with-context-api) article, it can interfere with composability (having one component inspect another's props no longer works well if you start wrapping and customizing components), and I tend to favor "explicit and composable" over "magical and elegant." But it's a perfectly valid technique.

**Other options**: You could try more advanced techniques, like using a portal to let a body render its heading elsewhere in the DOM - React's own [portal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) is designed for rendering into non-React nodes, but third-party components like [Material-UI's Portal](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-portal/) may provide some ideas. Or provide a [React context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) that lets each body register itself via `useEffect` to specify what tabs should be rendered. These options are more complicated and likely harder to maintain - I wouldn't go down this path unless the other options really wouldn't work for whatever reason.

Comment: as a newcomer, I find it quite weird that such a simple and useful structure is not possible without more or less silly hacks... I've updated the question to clarify what exactly I'm looking for.

Comment: @gog - Yes, you can do exactly what you're looking for using a component slots approach. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it easily.

Please refer below structure.

```
const App = () => {
    const [tab, setTab] = useState("tab1");

    return (
        <div>
            <div class="heads">
                <div onClick={()=>{setTab("tab1")}} class="head">head1</div>,
                <div onClick={()=>{setTab("tab2")}} class="head">head2</div>,
                <div onClick={()=>{setTab("tab3")}} class="head">head3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bodies">
                {{
                    "tab1": <div class="body">body1</div>,
                    "tab2": <div class="body">body2</div>,
                    "tab3": <div class="body">body3</div>
                }[tab]}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If you want dynamic tabs you can integrate like this

```
const App = () => {
    const [tabs, setTabs] = useState([
       {head: "Head 1", body: <div>body1</div>},
       {head: "Head 2", body: <div>body2</div>},
       {head: "Head 3", body: <div>body3</div>},
       {head: "Head 4", body: <div>body4</div>},
       {head: "Head 5", body: <div>body5</div>},       
       {head: "Head n", body: <div>bodyn</div>},
    ]);
    const [tab, setTab] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <div class="heads">
                {
                    tabs.map((tab, index) => (<div onClick={()=>{setTab(index)}}>{tab.head}</div>))
                }
            </div>
            <div class="bodies">
                {tabs?.[index]?.body}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And then you will get the same structure with

```
<Tabs ...>
    <Tab head="head1">body1</Tab>
    <Tab head="head2">body2</Tab>
    <Tab head="head3">body3</Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Just you will need to add CSS

```
// For example
.heads {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.bodies {
   padding: 4px;
   border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential way to go about this may be to create a custom component which takes in whatever "head" and "body" data you might want to render:
(Using typescript to enforce type checks and prevent silly errors)

```
 interface Props {
      head: React.ReactNode,
      body: React.ReactNode,
 }

 const CustomComponent = ({head, body}: Props) => {
      // add whatever logic you want here
      return () => {
           <div>{head}{body}</div>
      }
 }
```

You could take this a step further and pass in a a concrete data structure containing bunch of head, body data that you want to render and render that accordingly as you see fit.

Feel free to ask any and all questions!